# Octopus Deploy and VCloud compatibility

Tags: octopus-deploy

We are thinking of using Octopus deploy in our organization but our main concern is that our test environments are isolated. We use vCloud on all our test environments. I guess the question is can we use Octopus deploy to deploy code to a vCloud (VMare) environment when the Deploy server is outside of vCloud and all the test servers are inside the vCloud?

Comment: How isolated is "isolated"? Presumably there must be some way for someone to interface with systems in that environment.

Comment: Isolated in a sense that we cannot connect to servers outside of the environment. But there are instances when we have to open up our firewall to a server but since all the servers have the same name as the production servers we don't let SQL servers to communicate out of the environment. Typically if we are opening up the firewall it is usually incoming transactions and not outgoing.

Answer (score 0):

Octopus Deploy works in a push-based deployment model. The Octopus server 'pushes' deployments to the Tentacles (deployment agents). So if you can open the firewall inside VCloud to allow the Tentacle agents to listen on a TCP port, and allow the Octopus to connect into VCloud on that port, you should have no problems deploying into a VCloud environment.